# keypress не отслеживает стрелки на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно что-бы иммено когда держишь кнопку выводилась буква поэтому `keyup` и `keydown` не подойдут

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отслеживания "стрелок" надо слушать `keydown`:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.key);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо как можно скорее отмечу